# Счетчик вопросов/ответов на главной странице

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено

Как я понимаю, одной из главных задач сообщества на данный момент - это достижение отметки 80% отвеченных вопросов. В связи с этим вопрос/предложение:
почему бы по примеру https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ не сделать на главной странице, наряду с  колонкой "Важное на Мете", визуальный счетчик вида:

> Вопросов: Всего/Отвечено/% отвеченных

Кроме того, для общей информации можно выводить количество пользователей и другую статистическую информацию, отражающую активность сообщества.

ИМХО, достичь цели проще, если видеть к чему стремиться.

Comment: На сколько могу судить, такую информацию добавить можно. Предлагаю сообществу проголосовать за или против добавления.

Comment: Приложите плиз ссылку на обсуждение, где "одной из главных задач сообщества на данный момент - это достижение отметки 80% отвеченных вопросов"

Comment: К такому умозаключению меня подтолкнуло оживленное обсуждение вопросов  "Долгосрочные цели для сообщества StackOverflow на русском языке", "Как считается статистика отвечаемости вопросов на Area 51" и "Некоторые цифры по ru.SO"

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev спасибо за предложение! Блок добавлен!

Comment: Процент отвеченных неплохо бы отображать с точностью до сотых долей.

Comment: Кстати, счетчик вроде бы пропал.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Я голосую «**за**» добавление счетчика в боковую панель статистики сообщества.

Answer (score 0):

Я голосую «**против**» добавления счетчика в боковую панель статистики сообщества.